# Issue plotting selected columns of a data-frame on a map based on the values of another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am new to python programming.
I have a csv file with over 1000 rows. I will like to plot the columns (latitude and longitude) based on the value of the column (peak current) on a map. I usually get error messages whenever I load the data using pandas DataFrame. However, when I type the values for the latitude and longitude (for the first 10 values), everything seems alright. Although I have not been able to plot the lat/long based on peak current in the data frame, for the selected data point. I would want to know how to do it. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

This is my code

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lon_0=2

#Loading data

#df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
#lons = df['longitude']
#lat = df['latitude']

lons = [30.59294,30.593789,30.586066,30.648234,30.646268,30.633628,30.66251,29.531931,30.656409,30.708208]
lat = [-26.67026,-26.651906,-26.650199,-27.012214,-27.002663,-26.982482,-26.739707,-26.795177,-26.995863,-26.766377]

#coordinates
#llcrnrlat,llcrnrlon,urcrnrlat,urcrnrlon
# are the lat/lon values of the lower left and upper right corners of the map.
# lat_ts is the latitude of true scale.

m = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=lon_0,resolution='l',\
        llcrnrlat=-36,urcrnrlat=-21,llcrnrlon=15,urcrnrlon=34,)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()



# draw parallels and meridians.
parallels = np.arange(-90.,91.,5.)
# Label the meridians and parallels
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
# Draw Meridians and Labels
meridians = np.arange(-180.,181.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')



x,y = m(lons, lat)
plt.plot(x, y, '*',markersize=5)

plt.show()
```

I usually get error messages if I uncomment the line below to load data using pandas

```
#df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
#lons = df['longitude']
#lat = df['latitude']
```

This is a section of the data I am trying to load

```
    timestamp                   latitude    longitude   peakcurrent icheight    numbersensors   majoraxis   minoraxis   bearing
 2016-01-07T19:00:00.206710100          -26.67026   30.59294    -38161         0            6     0.1          0.1      10.9
 2016-01-07T19:00:00.262988806          -26.651906  30.593789   -49949         0            6     0.1          0.1      13.9
 2016-01-07T19:00:00.387655020          -26.650199  30.586066   27485          0            6     0.51         0.24     10.9
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.242107391          -27.012214  30.648234   -39139         0            6     0.79         0.2      20.9
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.353171110          -27.002663  30.646268   53449          0            6     0.17         0.11     13.3
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.410721779          -26.982482  30.633628   -31396         0            6     0.95         0.64     33.9
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.446598530          -26.739707  30.66251    53774          0            6     0.66         0.12     13.5
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.452036619          -26.795177  29.531931   -36773         0            6     2            0.37     39
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.524655104          -26.995863  30.656409   33640          0            6     1.5          0.37     33.7
 2016-01-07T19:00:02.617701054          -26.766377  30.708208   -74489         0            7     1.23         0.37     21
```

Comment: Can you fix your data preview, it’s not showing up.

Comment: Thanks, @BertilJohannesIpsen I just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the values of `long` and `lat` appropriately. Here is the relevant code that is corrected.

```
# ...
lons = df.longitude.values  # needs .values here
lats = df.latitude.values   # same as above

x, y = m(lons, lats)
plt.plot(x, y, '*', markersize=60, zorder=20, alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

The output plot will be (using sample data) similar to this:

[image: africa]